# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in videoProcessor.php

Tags: php

Here is my code and am getting a warning as `Trying to access array offset on value of type null` in the `videoProcessor.php` file. Please help me with this:

```
<?php
class VideoProcessor {

    private $con;
    private $sizeLimit = 500000000;
    private $allowedTypes = array("mp4", "flv", "webm", "mkv", "vob", "ogv", "ogg", "avi", "wmv", "mov", "mpeg", "mpg");

    public function __construct($con) {
        $this->con = $con;
    }

    public function upload($videoUploadData) {

        $targetDir = "uploads/videos/";
        $videoData = $videoUploadData->videoDataArray;
        
        $tempFilePath = $targetDir . uniqid() . basename($videoData["name"]);
        

        $tempFilePath = str_replace(" ", "_", $tempFilePath);

        $isValidData = $this->processData($videoData, $tempFilePath);
    }

    private function processData($videoData, $filePath) {
        $videoType = pathInfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        
        if(!$this->isValidSize($videoData)) {
            echo "File too large. Can't be more than " . $this->sizeLimit . " bytes";
            return false;
        }
        else if(!$this->isValidType($videoType)) {
            echo "Invalid file type ";
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function isValidSize($data) {
        return $data["size"] <= $this->sizeLimit;
    }

    private function isValidType($type) {
        $lowercased = strtolower($type);
        return in_array($lowercased, $this->allowedTypes);
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Which line is giving the error? Can you post the error message?

Comment: What array data you're passing to the ``upload `` function. Add sample data !!

Comment: $tempFilePath = $targetDir . uniqid() . basename($videoData["name"]);
return $data["size"] <= $this->sizeLimit;
these two lines have this warrning